# Converter para AbstractEditPageBean

Tags: demoiselle

Criei uma classe de domínio cuja chave primária é composta. Criei um *converter* para a classe da chave primária.

Registrei o *converter* no `faces-config`, além de usar a anotação `@FacesConverter` na classe do conversor, com o *ID* no `value`, e o `forClass`. Mas parece que a página de edição herdada de `AbstractEditPageBean` não está conseguindo encontrar o meu conversor, retornando a seguinte mensagem:

> "Você precisa criar um FacesConverter para a classe "...".

Será que preciso fazer algo mais, registrar em outro local?

Observações:

- Em outros locais o converter está funcionando normalmente, como na tela de lista
- Arquétipo Demoiselle jsf-jpa 2.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Parece que o método `getIdConverter()` da classe AbstractEditPageBean não está conseguindo recuperar o meu converter. Consegui resolver da maneira abaixo, mas ainda acho que não é o ideal.

Sobrescrevi o método `getId()` na minha página de edição, onde `id` é o parâmetro:

```
@Override
public MyCompositeKey getId() {
    MyConverter converter = new MyConverter();
    return (MyCompositeKey) converter.getAsObject(null, null, id.getValue());
}
```

Fernando

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver de outra maneira, também não sei se é a ideal. Fiz uma cópia da classe abstrata `AbstractEditPageBean`, chamando-a de `AbstractEditPageBeanConverter` e adicionando a classe do *converter* para o ID:

```
public abstract class AbstractEditPageBeanConverter <T, I, C> extends...
    ...
    private Class<C> converterForIdClass;
    ...
    protected Class<C> getConverterForIdClass() {
        if (this.converterForIdClass == null) {
            this.converterForIdClass = Reflections.getGenericTypeArgument(this.getClass(), 2);
        }
        return this.converterForIdClass;
    }
    ...
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public I getId() {
        Converter converter;
        try {
            converter = (Converter) getConverterForIdClass().newInstance();
        ...
        return (I) converter.getAsObject(facesContext, facesContext.getViewRoot(), id.getValue());
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o que estava fazendo que não funcionava.

Para a classe da entidade, eu anotei o converter com o `value` e o `forClass`:

```java
@FacesConverter(value="ConversorMinhaClasse", forClass=MinhaClasse.class)  
public class MinhaClasseConverter implements Converter...
```

Já para a classe da chave composta, se usar o `value` não funciona, então anotei o converter sem isso:

```java
@FacesConverter(forClass=MinhaChaveComposta.class)  
public class MinhaChaveCompostaConverter implements Converter
```